# How to see the grub menu once I had updated my OS

Tags: dual-boot

I updated my Ubuntu and I was asked to restart my PC on restart I cant see any selection option to select the Os but instead its going directly to windows10

Comment: can you add more details, the pc details

Answer (score 0):

try either of them:

- turn off secure boot in bios if it's turned on
- run ubuntu from usb and from there install `boot-repair` and run it
- run ubuntu from usb and from there follow http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd